# Find the derivative of the function $f(x)=(5-x^2)(\sqrt{x})$

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on this question, not sure what I am doing wrong:
\begin{align*}
 f(x) &=(5-x^2)(\sqrt{x}) \\
\\
 f'(x) &=(5-x^2)(x)^{1/2} \\
&=(-2x)(x)^{1/2}+(-x^2+5)(\dfrac{1}{2})(x)^{-1/2}\\
&=-2x^{3/2}+\dfrac{1}{2}(-x^{3/2}+5x^{-1/2})\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\bigg(x^2-2x^2+10\bigg)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\bigg(-x^2+10\bigg)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$-2x^{3/2}+\dfrac{1}{2}(-x^{3/2}+5x^{-1/2})\not =\dfrac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\bigg(x^2-2x^2+10\bigg).$$

We have
$$f'(x)=\cdots=-2x^{3/2}+\dfrac{1}{2}(-x^{3/2}+5x^{-1/2})=\frac 12x^{-\frac 12}(-4x^2-x^2+5)=\frac{5(1-x^2)}{2\sqrt x}.$$

Comment: Very clear, thank you!

Comment: @nitrous2: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Answer

In your fourth step:

$f'(x) = \frac{-5}{2}x^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{5}{2}x^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

$f'(x) =-\frac{5}{2}\left(\frac{x^2 -1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$